# How to change the font formatting in the text and numbers of footnotes in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, footnotes, fontsize, context, context-mkiv

I have a document with two different types of footnotes, `\noteone` and `\notetwo`, defined with this:

```
\definenote[noteone][footnote]
\definenote[notetwo][footnote]
```

For these two footnotes, I need to indepently set the fonts and font sizes, using `\ssa\bf`, `\cga\bf` etc., so they have a distinguishable appearance. Each type of footnote has three parts to be independently set:

```
- The number appearing in the body text.
- The number appearing next to the note, at the bottom of the page.
- The text appearing in the note at the bottom of the page.
```

I spent many hours in trial-and-error, while consulting the ConTeXt Garden's articles on http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes, http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupfootnotes, and the relevant material at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unexpected_behavior while trying to adjust the fonts.

I found many commands that are used to adjust the settings:

- `\setupfootnotes`
- `\setupfootnotedefinition`
- `\setupnote`
- `\setupnotation`

I also found that these commands can be adjusted with many settings:

- `bodyfont`
- `style`
- `numbercommand`
- `textcommand`
- `textstyle`

I could not determine which were the proper ones to adjust the font settings for the footnote's number in the text, the footnote's number near the note at the bottom of the page, and the footnote's note text at the bottom of the page.

How can I change the fonts and font sizes of the various components of footnotes in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need the two commands `\setupnotation` and `\setupnote`.

```
\setuppapersize [A5]  %% for a smaller screenshot

\definenote [noteone] [footnote]
\definenote [notetwo] [footnote]

%%     style - footnote text placed at the bottom of the page
%% headstyle - footnote number placed at the bottom of the page
%%
\setupnotation [noteone] [style=bold,   headstyle=\ttd]
\setupnotation [notetwo] [style=italic, headstyle=\ttb]

%% footnote number that appears in the body text
%%
\setupnote [noteone] [textstyle=\ssd]
\setupnote [notetwo] [textstyle=\ssb]

\starttext
  \input ward
  \startnoteone
    \input ward
  \stopnoteone \blank

  \input ward
  \startnotetwo
    \input ward
  \stopnotetwo
\stoptext
```

- `\setupfootnotes` - synonym for `\setupnote[footnote]`
- `\setupfootnotedefinition` - synonym for `\setupnotation[footnote]`
- `\setupnote` - layout of the note block, e.g. interline spacing
- `\setupnotation` - layout of the note entry, uses the same keys as enumerations/descriptions

I can't list all the possible keys for `\setupnotation` and `\setupnote`. Have
a look at the [definition of `\setupnotation`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/strc-not.mkvi#line77) and the [definition of
`\setupnote`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/strc-not.mkvi#line333).

Screenshot (context 2013.07.24 14:11):

[image: result]

Comment: These options, such as \setupnote[noteone][textstyle=\ssd], do not change the font size of any of the numbers. The font size seems fixed to font size `x`. How do I adjust the size of the numbers?

Comment: @Village I added a screenshot. As you can see, the font size change was applied. If it doesn't work for you, create a minimal working example and approach the mailing list.